# Is there a quick way to convert a .dae file to a .osg file?

Tags: collada, openscenegraph

So is there a quick way to convert a .dae file (COLLADA) to a .osg (OpenSceneGraph) file?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the collada loader plugin and the standard command line osg utils?  If so,

```
osgconv FILE.dae FILE.osg
```

from a command line will do it.

If you don't have the COLLADA plugin, you can use sketchup with Ryan Pavlik's osg exporter: https://github.com/rpavlik/sketchupToOSG

As a side note, this means it is super-simple to get anything from Google's 3D Warehouse into osg native formats, which means tons of great models.

Comment: Ahh, okay, because I did indeed try the osgconv but I don't think I had the COLLADA plugin. When i tried the to do the osgconv command line, I got a massive amount of text just vomiting onto my terminal

Comment: What is I am not suing sketch up? What plugin would I use from there

Comment: Sketchup is a little free modeling software - it was formerly owned by google, but they just sold it: http://sketchup.google.com/ - Download the free version which can import DAE, then you can use the plugin above to export to OSG.  The plugin, by the way, is just osgconv with the proper plugins to read Collada.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The app does not seem to want to import the DAE file. Perhaps it is a technical issue on my part because the inter webs are telling me that I should be able to import a COLLADA file

Comment: Also does this plugin work on Apple computers? I'm not very used to the OSx system but I have to use it for work.

Comment: Yes, it does have the option to import Collada:   File - Import... - Then change the file type dropbox to Google Earth/COLLADA.  Re: Mac - sketchup is available.  It doesn't look like the osg exporter is available for it, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From what i remember the Blender 2.49 was able to import Collada files and export OpenSceneGraph files.

You can give it a tray and download this version of Blender plus the exporter for OSG.

http://forum.openscenegraph.org/viewtopic.php?p=40070#40070

http://download.blender.org/release/

Answer (score 0):

There is also an .osg exporter for 3DS Max: http://osgmaxexp.wiki.sourceforge.net

You can import your .dae there and then use the exporter to create an .osg.